Запятая в ССП перед "и всё хорошо" в конце предложения
В таком предложении:
К тому же он живет там уже несколько лет и всё хорошо.
или:
К тому же он живет там уже несколько лет, и всё хорошо.
К тому же — общее слово в данном случае, или всё-таки это две части сложносочинённом?

С чем связана минусовка вопроса при отсутствии ответа?

Правильно:
К тому же он живет там уже несколько лет, и всё хорошо.
Пояснение
Это ССП, две предикативные основы.
К тому же — присоединительный союз, а союзы не являются общим элементом для ССП. Присоединительное значение союза  определяется по отношению к предыдущему тексту.
Справочник
Присоединительные обороты, начинающиеся союзом «к тому же», выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми. После слов «к тому же» запятая не ставится.

Второй ответ
К тому же он живет там / уже несколько лет, // и всё хорошО.
Вот любим мы работать с одним предложением, которое как бы существует само по себе. Что было раньше, что будет потом — что нам за дело! Нам знаки надо поставить.
Общий элемент в ССП? О, это сложное дело! Там элементарно можно поставить знаки по слуху и их объяснить. Я ставлю запятую. А почему?
По грамматике отношения между предложениями должны быть однородными, то есть не связанными причинно-следственными или другими отношениями.
Так у нас однородные отношения: Он живет там уже несколько лет,  всё хорошо.  Запятую вот можно поставить.
А что означает к тому же, контекст нужен. Вполне можно представить, что здесь уступительные отношения: тем не менее всё хорошо.  И тогда однородности нет, запятую нужно ставить.
Про интонацию (паузы и ударения)  я уж и не говорю. Проговорить текст предложения в одну фонетическую фразу довольно затруднительно.
Правила Розенталя? Они далеко не однозначны и допускают варианты толкования. Слово может быть общим, а может и не быть.
Вообще говоря, мне это правило представляется корректирующим по смыслу и отчасти по структуре, но формализм  здесь (как, впрочем, и везде) просто зашкаливает. Союз И может выражать разные отношения, в том числе в зависимости от контекста, но это уходит от внимания пользователей.
Можно посмотреть тему: https://proza.ru/2022/10/05/622
